# Creating a dropdown list in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm trying to create a dropdown select list in `Yii2` but am finding the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#dropDownList%28%29-detail) for it a bit confusing considering there are no examples.

Could someone attempt to explain it a bit better with some examples, like if I wanted to create a dropdown list like the below how would I do it?

Sample:

```
<select name="foo" id="bar" onchange="run()">
    <option value="">Select Pet Type</option>
    <option value="fish">Fish</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="lizard">Lizard</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply try this :

```
<?= Html::dropDownList('foo', null, [
    'fish' => 'Fish',
    'dog' => 'Dog',
], ['id' => 'bar', 'prompt'=>'Select Pet Type', 'onchange' => 'run()']) ?>
```

Or with a form and model :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'attribute')->dropDownList([
    'fish' => 'Fish',
    'dog' => 'Dog',
], ['id' => 'bar', 'prompt'=>'Select Pet Type', 'onchange' => 'run()']) ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I just got a bit confused with what went where with regards to the `items` and `options` parts as I didn't find it very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this, it will run.

```
<?php $dataList = Array('fish' => "Fish", 'dog' => "Dog", 'cat' => "Cat", 'lizard' => "Lizard"); ?>
<?php echo Html::dropDownList('foo', null, $dataList, [
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'id' => 'bar',
    'prompt' => 'Select Pet Type',
    'onchange' => 'run()'
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the model as it will be helpful for you to assign the values and perform validations and other useful functions like beforeSave or beforeValidate using model. So following code will work for you.

```
           <?php
           echo $form->field($model, 'foo')
                ->dropDownList(
                    ['fish' => 'Fish', 'dog' => 'Dog', 'cat' => 'Cat', 'lizard' => 'Lizard'],
                    ['prompt' => 'Select Pet Type', 'id' => 'bar']
                );
            ?>
```